# How to save variables before killing a (too long) running python script?

Tags: python-3.x

I've been running a **python script**  using:

- python
- Anacondaon
- linux server (4.15.0-36-generic #39~16.04.1-Ubuntu)

For two weeks now and I think it will take more than a month to finish. This is already too long and so I would like to kill the process but before that I would like to save some lists that have been constructed during the last two weeks.

So far I tried:

1) using pyrasite-shell with one the PID associated with my python script (I've more than 20 PIDs associated with my script according to htop) but it does not work (no shell opens).

2) I also tried to find some kernel address using `ps -aux | grep python3` and then connect to this kernel via something like `ipython console --existing d3d55f0d-52f1-4660-a43b-1fedb698452f.json` and then look for local variables with `locals()`in the prompt shell but this did not work (none of my lists appear in the list of local variables).

Ideally, I would like to connect the python kernel running my code and save all the current lists via pickle. Or any other idea to retrieve the lists would be great.

Comment: how about a finally statement with try/catch?

Comment: Colloquially you setup a logging system like this *before* you run your script...have you tried `rconsole`?

Comment: No, I've not tried `rconsole` (and I did not find any information about it). What is it? do you have some link that may explain how that works? Thanks.